# Creating Stats page. Php

Tags: php, sql, while-loop

I am trying to create a stat page within my website to display products belonging to a trader, the amount of each product sold and the total price of the certain product that has been sold.

My code at the moment creates a while loop but as it loops through the database, it displays the items multiple times (instead of just the once for each product) and the total amount of each product sold isn't set to a certain product, it is showing the total amount for every product sold.

Here is my select statement:

```
      $querytest = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT
                    INNER JOIN TRADER
                    ON PRODUCT.Stall_ID=TRADER.Stall_ID
                    INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS
                    ON PRODUCT.Product_ID=ORDER_ITEMS.Product_ID
                    WHERE TRADER.Username='". $_SESSION['Username'] ."'";

      $testresult = oci_parse($connection, $querytest);
      oci_execute($testresult)
```

Here is my while loop. I wish for it to only output the products in the database once. But it is outputting them numerous times.

```
    while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($testresult)) {
      $DName = $row ['NAME'];
      $DProdesc = $row ['PRODUCT_DESC'];
      $DIMAGEID = $row['IMAGEID'];
      $DPrice = $row['PRICE'];

      $price = $row['PRICE'];

      $prodord = $row['PRODUCTQUANTITY'];

      $totalprodord = $totalprodord + $prodord;

      $totalprodprice = $totalprodord * $Dprice;

      $quantity = $row['QUANTITY'];

      $subtotal = ($price * $quantity);

      $total = $total + $subtotal;

      $stock = $stock + $quantity;





            echo  '<td> <img src="' . $DIMAGEID.  '" height="50" width="50"/></td>';
            echo  '<td>' .$DName. '</td>';
            echo  '<td>' .$DProdesc. '</td>';
            echo '<td>' .$totalprodord. '</td>';
            echo '<td>&pound; ' .$DPrice.  '</td>';
                  echo '<td>&pound; ' . $totalprodprice . '</td>';'</tr>';
    }


      ob_flush();
      ?>
```

My database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TRADER(
    Trader_ID number (5) NOT NULL,
    Trader_Name varchar2 (20),
    FirstName varchar2 (10) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar2 (10) NOT NULL,
    DOB date NOT NULL,
    Username varchar2 (15) NOT NULL,
    Password varchar2 (32) NOT NULL,
    Phone varchar2 (10),
    Email varchar2 (30) NOT NULL,
    Stall_ID number (5) references STALL(Stall_ID),
    Primary Key (Trader_ID));

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT(
    Product_ID number (5) NOT NULL,
    Name varchar2 (30) NOT NULL,
    Product_Desc varchar2 (50),
    ImageID varchar2 (35),
    Price number(5,2) NOT NULL,
    Quantity number (10) NOT NULL,
    Stall_ID number (5) references STALL(Stall_ID),
    Product_Type_ID number (5) references PRODUCT_TYPE(Product_Type_ID),
    Primary Key (Product_ID));

CREATE TABLE ORDER_ITEMS(
    Order_Items_ID number (5) NOT NULL,
    TotalPrice number (5,2) NOT NULL,
    ProductQuantity number (5) NOT NULL,
    Day_ID number (5) references COLLECTION_DAY(Day_ID),
    Time_ID number (5) references COLLECTION_TIME(Time_ID),
    Customer_ID number (5) references CUSTOMER(Customer_ID),
    Product_ID number (5) references PRODUCT(Product_ID),
    Order_ID number (5) references CUSTOMER_ORDER(Order_ID),
    Primary Key (Order_Items_ID));
```

Can anybody please help me to get the stats showing correctly?

Thanks

Comment: The HTML blob is not relevant to your question. Instead explain your table scheme and content. Give an example on what you want grouped.

Comment: In first place I would say... separate your html and php. Secondly the echo's aren't relevant to your question. Third: please provide more information like your database scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need sum up your numbers in your query, or you have to sum up numbers and skip identical products in your code. You are doing neither.

Try replace your query with something like this:

```
SELECT prod.product_id, prod.name, 
prod.quality-sum(orders.quality) AS Stock_Left, 
AVG(orders.price) AS Sold_price, 
SUM(orders.price * orders.quality) AS Sold_Amount, 
Sum(orders.quality) AS Total_Sold 
FROM product prod INNER JOIN Order_Items orders
ON prod.prod_id = orders.prod_id 
INNER JOIN trader 
ON prod.stall_id = trader.stall_id
WHERE trader.Username='". $_SESSION['Username'] ."'"
```

You can get rid of most your calculations in the loop.